# How to Hide Screen on Pause in Ionic App for iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins

I am developing a mobile app for iOS using Ionic Framework 4 with Cordova/PhoneGap.  The app contains sensitive information.  One of the requirements is that the screen become hidden/blank whenever the user pauses the app (i.e. when they press the Home button).

Normally iOS takes a snapshot of the current screen whenever the user presses the Home button.  This snapshot needs to be blank.

Is there a plugin for Cordova/PhoneGap or Ionic Native which can be used to  make the screen blank?

It appears that this cannot be accomplished through JavaScript inside the webview.  The pause can be detected but no interactive code works at that point, so it is too late to blank out the screen.  See http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0rc1/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause

The pause can be intercepted earlier by native iOS code, but this would require a Cordova/PhoneGap plugin.  I am hoping someone here can recommend a plugin that can detect the pause and hide the screen.

Comment: maybe this can help u : https://github.com/devgeeks/PrivacyScreenPlugin

Comment: @Sam - Thanks for sharing.  This looks promising.  I'll try it and update my post after I'm able to test.